# Conversion String to JSONArray result to an error

Tags: android, arrays, json, type-conversion, android-volley

I am trying to convert a string to JSONArray but each time there is a JSONException, I do not know how to freeze the problem.

```
    [
         {"color_gr":0,
          "color":0,
          "profil":"",
          "name":null,
          "role":"",
          "date_last":78554,
          "date_":0,"plus":78,
          "did":"FlaRize",
          "id":"flarize45 "
         }
         ,
         {
          "color_gr":0,
          "color":1,
          "profil":"je suis ",
          "name":"#TUEURS ",
          "role":"#PROGRAMMEURSD ",
          "date_last":45888888,
          "date_":487,
          "plus":78,
          "did":"FlaRize",
          "id":"gg "
         }
     ]
```

This is the string that I'm trying to convert into JSONArray

The java code:
    - response = who comes from the server.

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
 JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
 ElementChat elementChat = new ElementChat(
       jsonObject.getInt("color_gr"),
       jsonObject.getInt("color"),
       jsonObject.getString("profil"),
       jsonObject.getString("name"),
       jsonObject.getString("role"),
       jsonObject.getLong("date_last"),
       jsonObject.getLong("date_"),
       jsonObject.getLong("plus"),
       jsonObject.getString("did"),
       jsonObject.getString("id")
 );
```

I don't really know how to convert this string in jsonArray.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Is response coming from server using Retrofit?

Comment: you are doing this incorrectly

Comment: name is null here, that possible throwing a exception ...try putting if(jsonObject.getString(name!= null))

Comment: I tried to find when the error appears is so it's up to JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

Comment: I am using volley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray .length(); i++) {
       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
       ElementChat elementChat = new ElementChat(
           jsonObject.getInt("color_gr"),
           jsonObject.getInt("color"),
           jsonObject.getString("profil"),
           jsonObject.getString("name"),
           jsonObject.getString("role"),
           jsonObject.getLong("date_last"),
           jsonObject.getLong("date_"),
           jsonObject.getLong("plus"),
           jsonObject.getString("did"),
           jsonObject.getString("id")
     );
}
```

Comment: i make synthax error when i copy ur code now it's working thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> Try below

As General Thing,

```
ArrayList<OBJECT> yourArray = new Gson().fromJson(myjsonarray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<OBJECT>>(){}.getType());
```

In your case do like below

```
ArrayList<ElementChat> yourArray = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<ElementChat>>(){}.getType());
```